# MS Access: listbox appears to be locked when assigned to ID's on continous form

Tags: sql, t-sql, ms-access, vba

I have a continuous form where i have a listbox assigned to an ID. I cant seem to select anything in the list box. I have the row source property set to a Value List. I manually typed in "Y";"N" for the list.

If I don't assign the control source to the ID, all listboxes are selected at once on the form.

Is there any property I should change?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot sensibly use unbound controls on a continuous form.

Comment: i have had this work one time before. there's got to be a away to do it again.